# lazy load images issue in uicollectionview

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am new to iOS app development. I am working on lazy load of images for `UICollectionView`. The Image are showing but when I scroll the `UICollectionView`, images change their positions and there are repetition of images where all the images should be unique. Here is my code:

```
- (MyCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.imageview_collectnvw.layer.cornerRadius=6.0f;
    cell.imageview_collectnvw.layer.masksToBounds=YES;

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("patientlist",NULL);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{


        NSString *str=[[[search_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"friend"]valueForKey:@"linkedin_photo"];

        NSLog(@"cell index path --- is %d",indexPath.row);

        NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if ([[collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems] containsObject:indexPath]) {

                MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                cell.imageview_collectnvw.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

            }

            [cell setNeedsLayout];

            NSLog(@"cell index path main is %d",indexPath.row);

        });
    });


    return cell;
}
```

This may be a silly question but I need the answer.. It will be of great help if anyone can answer this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

When working with `UICollectionView` you should use `indexPath.item` instead of `indexPath.row`.

Comment: what about when i need to use both section and row?

Comment: you can still access the `section` property of `indexPath`

Comment: should i use section and item instead section and row respectively?

Answer (score 3):

In a `UICollectionView` or a `UITableView`, the cells are reused and that's what you are getting at the line where you call `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`. So, you get an older cell which had images assigned to it to begin with and you are not explicitly setting it to nil before calling the async call, it will still have the older image until the new one is downloaded and set. So, the fix is to assign `cell.imageview_collectnvw.image` to nil or a placeholder image until the download is successful.  Also, manage an array of `UIImages` that is cached in memory and removed from memory as required for better performance. Check out `SDWebImage` which does both caching into memory and disk and  has got a fantastic performance as far as I have seen. A good start to understand how to setup image loading in a table or `UICollectionView` is have a look at lazyloading example by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for lazy loading. It will load images assynchronously then cache images and no need to load it again and again

Comment: in SDWebImage its showing ld: framework not found SDWebImage-3.3
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) but i have import the error and added -ObjC in other linker

Answer (score 0):

You must be using multiple sections and rows. But you are loading images only with indexPath.row which might become duplicated for different sections. Hence your section images are supposed to be duplicated. Please assure that your key is generated both using section and item.

#### For Swift

```
func getCachedIndexKey(index:NSIndexPath) -> String {
    return "section:\(index.section)item:\(index.item)"
}
```

This method will return a unique key (although in string). Please understand the situation and prepare your own unique index key (integer).